# When I should mask UITableView section cell corners?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mask, rounded-corners

I am trying to make rounded corner section cells by indexpath.row. Sometimes mask is running but sometimes not. Why is this happening?

Here is my mask code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row > 0 {
        //Child Subjects
        let myCell = cell as! SubSubjectTableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
            rectShape.bounds = myCell.containerView.frame
            rectShape.position = myCell.containerView.center
            rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myCell.containerView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)).cgPath

            //Here I'm masking
            myCell.containerView.layer.mask = rectShape
        }
        else if indexPath.row == highSchoolSubject[indexPath.section].childs.count {
            let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
            rectShape.bounds = myCell.containerView.frame
            rectShape.position = myCell.containerView.center
            rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myCell.containerView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)).cgPath

            //Here I'm masking
            myCell.containerView.layer.mask = rectShape
        }
        else {
            myCell.containerView.layer.mask = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to apply mask from cellForRowAt method but no difference.

Results:

[image]

Also why it looks from the top of the parent cell?

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCell is changed internally before being displayed. I recommend you to make maskToBounds in willDisplayCell method of the UITableViewDelegate, or put the same sized.

or you can try this too:

You need to add `cell.layer.maskToBounds = true` .

Comment: I tried first suggestion and `cell.layer.maskToBounds = true` end of the willDisplayCell method but not working. I did not understand how to put the same sized?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cell.clipsToBounds = true` in willDisplayCell or while the creation of the cell.

> The use case for clipsToBounds is more for subviews which are partially outside the main view. For example, I have a (circular) subview on the edge of its parent (rectangular) UIView. If you set clipsToBounds to YES, only half the circle/subview will be shown. If set to NO, the whole circle will show up. Just encountered this so wanted to share

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.